# Data Privacy Rasa NLU

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, rasa-nlu

I am using RASA NLU (open source), but I am concerned about data privacy. I want my data to be private, and wanted to ensure that none of my data ever leaves my machine, connects to Rasa's servers (or any servers other than my own —- only running locally), and nothing goes to the cloud. I want all my data to be private and local until deployment. Is this true of Rasa NLU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true. If you spin up an NLU server on a machine you have control over, no NLU data will go to any cloud server. Rasa specifically supports deploying an assistant (or just an NLU server) either on premise, or in the cloud (which also, incidentally, will not share your data unless you choose to do so - it's just another place to spin up a server), so it is up to you. There are no "Rasa servers" in the sense of servers providing the Rasa service unless you bring one up.